# Using OpenShift for non-web application?

Tags: openshift, zabbix

I tried to get a sysadmin to install Zabbix monitoring server (not agent) on OpenShift for me, to monitor some apps running elsewhere. He tells me that the zabbix server cannot be reached from remote agents due to OpenShift's restriction on non-web ports.

Is this true - only web applications can be run on OpenShift?

I understand you can hack port forwarding to reach non-web ports, but that's hardly a good solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This isnt' a programming question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stackoverflow is much more than programming! And OpenShift migrated their support team to Stackoverflow this year anyway...

Comment: Then why does it say "Is your question about programming?" in big friendly letters on the page where you ask questions? Your Q is "Can I run application X on platform Y?". Its a non-programming systems admin task. Try ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/search?q=openshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, you can only access web based applications on openshift servers, the following ports are open to the internet: 80/443/8000/8443, basically just http, https, and websockets (ws, wss) and they all listen internally on port 8080, no other public ports are exposed.  Those ports also go through an apache/node.js reverse proxy before they reach your gear.